# REACT JS AWS congnito Login with Social Medias

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to get social media creds with cognito (aaws amplify).
This method returns exactly what I need!

```
const RegWithSocialMedia = (e, social_media) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: social_media })
    .then(cred => {
        console.log(cred);
        return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    })
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    });
}
```

[This have the information I need (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WXG3.png)

I call this with onClick button event.
The problem is that this code refreshs the page after show me above obj and then I loss the infos.

How can I supress this 'refresh' when I call the Auth.federatedSignIn?

I'm using the aws-amplify version 3.3.26. The last version is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do what you are asking. TBH, I don't think you want to. You probably don't want to console.log the credentials.

If you need the current user's auth information, you can always use `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` in any of your React components.